# AZURE API Management Developer Portal - Forbidden When Attempting To View API

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

I am experiencing an issue with the Azure API Management Portal. I have a number of developers signed up on my portal and have been using various products and apis successfully for the last few months. We have made no new changes to the portal config or exposed services.  However when a developer logs into the portal, and tries to click on a given api link it displays a Forbidden page. The users are all set correctly in the appropriote groups and the correct products and apis are showing based on the user's access rights defined.  This isuue exists on new users and existing users.  Seemed to happen overnight . It was working fine last night but this morning developers can't get acess to apis. Micrsosoft are saying there are no wide issues.  If anyone has ever seen this id appreciate any help in resolving.

Comment: It must be on their side, I have the exact same issue, started 1/16/2018. I use AzureAD and ADB2C logins, if that helps when diagnosing.

Comment: We are also experiencing the same issue in both of our developer portals

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys. Do you have support tickets into Microsoft? I am just raising now with my client .  Ill feedback more when i know more.

Comment: We're on a bizspark plan that doesn't allow us to support tickets for technical support but I did tag their support team on twitter with a link to this SO post. Also, I noticed that when logging in to the portal as administrator, the 'forbidden' issue goes away